# I would like to put a text file in existing excel file on specific cell using python

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I would like to put text file(calculation log - not not in tabular form) in  existing excel file on specific cell.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

log=open('path')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('existing excel file', engine='xlsxwriter')

log.to_excel(writer , sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=57,startrow=1)

writer.save()
```

I put other dataframes like this.
However, this txt file cannot be made into a dataframe.

I want the txt file not to go into one cell, but like when I did control c + control v for the whole thing.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas to do that too. First, get your log with a context manager

```
with open('example text.txt', 'r') as file:
    log = file.read()
```

Get your excel file as a dataframe with no headers (column names will be the column numbers)

```
df = pd.read_excel('example excel.xlsx', header = None)
```

Put your text where you need it using column number and row number

```
df.at[row_number,column_number] = log
```

Then, if you need to, rewrite the excel file

```
df.to_excel('example excel.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: I get a new error message. df = pd.read_excel('example excel.xlsx', header = None) [BadZipFile: File is not a zip file]

Comment: This looks like a separate issue unfortunately. You can see more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817758/badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file-error-popped-up-all-of-a-sudden. Bottom line is: if you can, use a csv. Otherwise make sure what the file type is (xlsx, xls) and change the engine accordingly.