# zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file in pandas read Excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to fix a problem in a Airflow DAG, sometimes the script works fine, but sometimes the DAG gives me a error:

> WARNING - "File /usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1198, in _RealGetContents
> raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
> WARNING - zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file ERROR - Error save file directory

My code is:

```
files_path = os.path.join(local_path, '*')
files = sorted(glob.iglob(files_path), key=ps.path.getctime, reverse=True)
for i in files:
    if str(ste.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) == dateday:
        remaining.append(i)
lastfile = remaining[0]
df = pd.read_excel('{}'.format(last_file), engine='openpyxl')
```

Already tried: ["BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" - Error popped up all of a sudden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817758/badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file-error-popped-up-all-of-a-sudden)

The files is created by a RPA, is always a xlsx file, with same structure.

Comment: check this also probably will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11385480/17637655

Comment: I've no idea what an RPA but the exception tells you what you need to know: the file is not a valid zipfile and, therefore, not a valid XLSX file.

Comment: It's an automate process, always generate a xlsx at 9am. Always is a xlsx files