# Excel file corrupted after opening with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873423/xlsx-and-xlsm-files-return-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file) but a little bit different.

I open an excel file with openpyxl, which works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
file_name = 'Excel_File.xlsx'
```

Then I define a function which opens a sheet from the file and reads in data with the pandas package:

```
def exm_fct():
        sheet = 'sheet_name'
        read_data = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=sheet, engine='openpyxl', usecols="A:C", skiprows=1)

    return read_data
```

When I apply the function for the first time, everything goes right. But when I do it for the second time, I get the `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`-Error and the Excel File is corrupted and I can't even open it in Excel anymore.

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57817758/11286032

Comment: Not really, the suggested solution says that the file has to be the .xlsx format and the engine has to be specified as engine='openpyxl', which is both the case in my problem.